# Plotting events vs timestamps in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have data in a txt file in the following format:

2021-10-7 07:55:19 ;entry

2021-10-7 07:55:20 ;entry

2021-10-7 07:55:22 ;entry

2021-10-7 07:55:25 ;entry

2021-10-7 07:57:23 ;entry

2021-10-7 07:57:57 ;exit

And I am using Python to create a timeplot or an event plot, basically the timestamps on the x axis and to each time stamp I want to plot said event, I am currently using Pandas and I am trying to figure out how to go about it, this is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.read_csv('joined_results.txt', delim_whitespace=True, usecols=[0,1,2], names = ["Day", "Time", "Event"])
df2 = pd.read_csv('joined_results_video.txt',  delim_whitespace=True, usecols=[0,1,2], names = ["Day", "Time", "Event"],parse_dates=True)


df1['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1["Time"] , infer_datetime_format=True)

df1=df1.drop(columns=["Day", "Time"])



df1["Event"] = df1["Event"].apply(lambda x:x.replace(";",""))
df1["mydate"] = df1["mydate"].apply(lambda x:x.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
print(df1.head())

df_numpy= df1.to_numpy()

fig,axes=plt.subplots(1,1)
labels = []
for i in range (0,15):
    axes.scatter(df_numpy[i,1],df_numpy[i,0])
    labels.append(df_numpy[i,1])

plt.xticks(labels, rotation='vertical')
#axes.xaxis.set_ticks(df_numpy[:,1], rotation = 'vertical')
plt.margins(0.2)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
axes.set_title("Event Plot")
plt.show()
```

So I can tell I am almost there, its just that a few things are missing for me, which are the following: I'd like to display all of the points, but the x axis should be the timestamps in intervals of 30 minutes, so a total of 24 ticks for 12 hours, and I want that whenever I hover over a point, the exact timestamp should appear.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: just curious, why don't you read your data with `pd.read_csv(sep=';')`?

Comment: I was playing around with the sample data to try out a few things, will get to that in the end for sure